# Undefined index: reporter and reports

Tags: php

Hi whay i have this errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: reporter in /home/test.php on line 17
```

Line 17 is :
    if ($row_logs['reporter'] == sanitize($member['members_seo_name']))

```
Notice: Undefined index: reports in /home/test.php on line 25
```

Line 25 is :
    if ($row_max['reports'] == 4 && $row_max['rep_expire'] >= time() )

```
<?php
require_once("init.php");
global $db, $core;

$member['members_seo_name'] = "maximum";


      $username = "plusmaster";
      $rep_logs = $db->query("SELECT reporter FROM rep_logs WHERE reported = '" . $username . "'");
      $row_logs = $db->fetchrow($rep_logs);

    if ($row_logs['reporter'] == sanitize($member['members_seo_name']))
          echo 'Before that you are reported this user.';


      $seoname = sanitize($member['members_seo_name']);   
      $rep_max = $db->query("SELECT * FROM rep_max WHERE reporter = '" . $seoname . "'");
      $row_max = $db->fetchrow($rep_max);

    if ($row_max['reports'] == 4 && $row_max['rep_expire'] >= time() )
         echo 'Max report time reached.';

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Check your return values. A large percentage of questions on StackOverflow would be solved simply by checking that return values actually are what they are assumed to be.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410685/undefined-index-reporter-and-reports#comment45154859_28410685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means your query doesn't return any result use a check for count return rows

```
if(count($row_max) > 0) {
  // your code
}
```

also you can check with more ways with

`is_array($row_max)` or `isset($row_max['reports'])`

and according to array result you need to use array index like

```
if ($row_max[2] == 4 && $row_max[3] >= time() )
```

Comment: Additionally I suspect that $row_logs['reporter'] should become $rep_logs['reporter']

Comment: @jacek_podwysocki nope `$row_logs['reporter']` is correct  cause OP storing `$rep_logs['reporter'] `result in  `$row_logs['reporter']`

Comment: `$row_logs['reporter']`  not worked and also i tested with `count` its return result but also have same error and with `isset` just have white page!!

Comment: i use this code for error reporting but just have this 2 errors   `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: print_r($row_max); and post your result

Comment: This is result :  `Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => maximum [2] => 2 [3] => 1423572729 )  `   and the 0 = id , 1 = reports, 2 = rep_expire

Comment: try  `if ($row_max[1] == 4 && $row_max[2] >= time() )` use array index what array returning

Comment: use array index 2 and 3 according to array